# Radius of convergence of the power series $\sum x^{2^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

> Find the radius of convergence of the power series
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{2^n}.$$

Let , $u_n=x^{2^n}$. Then , $u_n^{1/n}=x^{\frac{2^n}{n}}$. Let, $m=\frac{2^n}{n}$

So, $m\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

As the series is convergent so, $\lim_{n\to \infty}u_n^{1/n}<1$ and it is possible only when $|x|<1$.

So the radius of convergence of the power series is $1$.

Am I right or wrong ?

If I am wrong what is my fault? Does there any other way to find it ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how the root criterion works. You look for the $n$-th root of the *coefficients*, not the power terms.

Write 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{2^n} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^k,
$$
where
$$
a_k = \begin{cases} 0 & k \neq 2^n~\text{for some}~n,\\ 1 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
and use this to find the radius of convergence. (You'll actually need the limsup as opposed to the naive limit here.)

Comment: Well...But why the root criteria does not work here??Using root criteria we found the domain of convergence..

Comment: It works, you're just not using it in the right way. That you ended up with the correct radius of convergence was a coincidence. You need to look for $\sqrt[k]{a_k}$, not $\sqrt[k]{x^{2^k}}$ - those are very different things.

Comment: No. For a few time you forget the concept of power series.Just take it as an infinite series.I use the root test for the series of the form $\sum u_n$.Let $\lim _{n\to \infty} u_n^{1/n}=l$. If $l<1$ then the series is convergent and if $l>1$ then the series is divergent. Using this I just find the condition on $x$ such that the series is convergent.

Comment: Ah, I see - you're using the root test for regular series, while I'm referring to the root test for power series. In that case I believe your method works, but it is an unusual approach for getting the radius of convergence of a power series. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test#Application_to_power_series to understand what I am referring to.